# Universal covering of maximal torus in a compact Lie group

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the universal covering of maximal torus $T$ of dimension $n$? of a compact Lie group $G$. Is there any reference?

Comment: You mean $\textbf{maximal torus}$ inside a Lie group?

Comment: yes, exactly of compact Lie group

Comment: I see. I shall venture to correct the typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{t}\rightarrow T$ will be the universal cover. (The exponential map for $G$ restricts to the one I have written.) To verify this explicitly, just consider the case $T=U(1)^n$ and $\mathfrak{t}=(i\mathbb{R})^n$. In this case, the exponential map is the usual exponential map in each factor.